# Applying a Function to a List and a Dataframe

Tags: python, function, apply

I have a single pair of longitude and latitude coordinates that will be inputted into a function to find the distance between it and a second pair of coordinates

For example:

```
lat_string1 = 48.167
long_string1 = -99.648
lat_string2 = 48.25606
long_string2 = -103.31802
```

Using Haversine Distance function I can find the distance between these two coordinates.

```
def dist(lat1, long1, lat2, long2):

    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lat1, long1, lat2, long2 = map(radians, [lat1, long1, lat2, long2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = long2 - long1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    # Radius of earth in kilometers is 6371
    km = 6371* c
    return km

print(dist(lat_string1, long_string1, lat_string2, long_string2))
272.09670525744474
```

How do I apply this function to `lat_string1` and `long_string1` and to `coordinates_df` containing 1,000's (or three in the example df below) of coordinate pairs so it may print every distance for A, B, and C?

```
lat_string1 = 48.167
long_string1 = -99.648    
coordinates_df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Longitude':[-102.65324700, -102.75365900, -102.90515700], 'Latitude':[48.47342600, 48.31341700, 48.11112400]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use apply:

```
coordinates_df['distance'] = coordinates_df.apply(lambda row : dist(lat_string1,long_string1,row['Latitude'],row['Longitude']),axis=1)
```

Then you can print it.

Comment: or better if your dist function supports brodcasting (ie numpy fonctions) you could do coordinates_df['distance']  = dist(lat_string1,long_string1,coordinates_df['Latitude'],coordinates_df['Longitude'])